# Pandas update selected rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update rows matching a selector. This is basically the behavior I want.

```
def select_rows(df, selector):
    return df.loc[(df[list(selector)] == pd.Series(selector)).all(axis=1)]

def update_matching(df, selector, update):
    selected = select_rows(df, selector)
    updated = selected.assign(**update)
    result = updated.combine_first(df)
    return result


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})

select_rows(df, {'b': 4})
# :    a  b
# : 1  2  4

update_matching(df, {'b': 4}, {'a': 99})
# :       a    b
# : 0   1.0  3.0
# : 1  99.0  4.0
```

1. Is there a simpler way to do this?
2. Why does the type change from `int` to `float`? How can I avoid this?

Comment: The complication arises from the fact that you're passing dictionaries. Just pass keys and values separately, that'd makes things simpler.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not quite seeing it. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Even better, you can just set `b` as the index using `df = df.set_index('b')` and then performing lookups and setting values is simple using `loc`.

Comment: Can you describe the logic behind the `update_matching()` function?  I see what the code is doing, but I'm not clear on why it's doing that, so it's a little hard to suggest a simpler method.

Comment: @ASGM Copy the dataframe, then update the rows specified by `selector` with new values specified by `update`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is my answer something like what you meant?

Answer (score 7):

There is indeed a simpler way to select rows based on column values:

```
df[df['b'] == 4]
```

And to update those rows:

```
df.loc[df['b'] == 4, 'a'] = 99
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that's essentially what my answer does, but with multiple selectors, multiple updaters like `assign()` does, and not-in-place. Do you see a way to do those more simply?

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative.

```
def select_indexes(df, selector):
  return (df[list(selector)] == pd.Series(selector)).all(axis=1)


def update_matching(df, selector, update):
    new = df.copy()
    update_keys, update_values = zip(*update.items())
    rows = select_indexes(new, selector)
    new.loc[rows, update_keys] = update_values
    return new
```